# Unique texts in row in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file with text and numerical data in the format shown in the following picture:

[image]

I am importing this file using `pandas` using the following command:

```
 df = pd.read_csv('dum.txt',sep='\t', header=[0,1], index_col=0)
```

In this file, I want to find the unique texts in the row called `Tag` (`['Tag1', 'Tag1', 'Tag1', Tag1, 'Tag5']`) as a python list. How can I do it?

When I use `df.columns`, I get this:

```
>>> df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'T1', u'T2', u'T3', u'T4', u'T5'], 
   [u'Tag1', u'Tag5']], labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 0, 
   0, 0, 1]], names=[u'Type', u'Tag'])
```

In the aforesaid example, how can I get the unique texts in the row called `Tag`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do `levels` with `tolist`

```
df.columns.levels[1].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks Wen! This helped me very much. I will accept your answer in a few minutes. =)